# How can I add a dll reference in C# without problems?

Tags: c#, dll

I'm kinda new at this, this is my first question here, but here it goes.

I've got a server and a client using TcpListenet and TcpClient, I also created a Class Library where I have my shared classes, I have already added the reference for this class in both the server and the client projects, I've also added the "using" statement to import this class. When I run both the client and the server on VS it works just fine, hoewever, when I try to test using multiple clients by opening the client.exe files, I get an error saying that my library could not be found, and also this:  Set the register value set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

I'm not sure why it works by running it on VS but not by executing the .exe files.
Please help me.

Comment: Copy *all* of the files in the project's bin\Release folder, not just the .exe

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Put your `DLL` to Global Assembly Cache(GAC)
2. For your files Properties "Build Action" as "Content" and for "Copy to output directory" as "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer" (this will put the file only when there are changes into it).